# How to treat date as plain text with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas to read a .csv file, then save it as .xls file. Code as following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='GB18030')
print(df)
df.to_excel('filename.xls')
```

There's a column contains date like '2020/7/12', it's looks like pandas recognized it as date and output it to '2020-07-12' automatically. I don't want to format this column, or any other columns like this, I'd like to keep all data remain the same as plain text.

This convertion happens at `read_csv()`, because `print(df)` already outputs YYYY-MM-DD, before `to_excel()`.

I tried use `df.info()` to check the data type of that column, the data type is object. Then I added argument `dtype=pd.StringDtype()` to `read_csv()` and it doesn't help.

The file contains Chinese characters so I set encoding to GB18030, don't know if this matters.

Comment: The problem maybe because of the default Date display of Excel program in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My experience concerning *pd.read_csv* indicates that:

- Only columns convertible to *int* or *float* are by default
  converted to respective types.
- "Date-like" strings are still read as **strings** (the column type in
  the resulting *DataFrame* is actually *object*).

If you want *read_csv* to convert such column to *datetime* type, you
should pass *parse_dates* parameter, specifying a list of columns to be
parsed as dates. Since you didn't do it, no source column should be
converted to *datetime* type.

To check this detail, after you read *file*, run `file.info()` and check
the type of the column in question.

So if respective *Excel* file column is of *Date* type, then probably
this conversion is caused by *to_excel*.

And one more remark concerning variable names:
What you have read using *read_csv* is a **DataFrame**, not a **file**.
Actual *file* is the **source** object, from which you read the content,
but here you passed only file **name**.

So don't use names like *file* to name the resulting DataFrame, as this
is misleading. It is much better to use e.g. *df*.

## Edit following a comment as of 05:58Z

To check in full extent what you wrote in your comment, I created
the following CSV file:

```
DateBougth,Id,Value
2020/7/12,1031,500.15
2020/8/18,1032,700.40
2020/10/16,1033,452.17
```

I ran: `df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')` and then `print(df)`, getting:

```
   DateBougth    Id   Value
0   2020/7/12  1031  500.15
1   2020/8/18  1032  700.40
2  2020/10/16  1033  452.17
```

So, at the *Pandas* level, no format conversion occurred in *DateBougth*
column. Both remaining columns, contain numeric content, so they were
silently converted to *int64* and *float64*, but *DateBought* remained as *object*.

Then I saved this *df* to an Excel file, running: `df.to_excel('Output.xls')`
and opened it with Excel. The content is:

[image]

So neither at the Excel level any data type conversion took place.

To see the actual data type of *B2* cell (the first *DateBougth*),
I clicked on this cell and pressed *Ctrl-1*, to display cell formatting.
The format is *General* (not *Date*), just as I expected.

Maybe you have some outdated version of software?
I use *Python* v. 3.8.2 and *Pandas* v. 1.0.3.

Another detail to check: Look at your code after *pd.read_csv*.
Maybe somewhere you put instruction like *df.DateBought = pd.to_datetime(df.DateBought)* (explicit type conversion)?
Or at least format conversion. Note that in my environment
there was absolutely no change in the format of *DateBought* column.

Comment: Thanks, the data type of that column is exactly object, but when I tried print that column (before `to_excel()`), the output is still formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. Really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I double checked my `.csv` file, opened it with notepad, the data is `2020-07-12`, which displays as `2020/7/12` on Office. Turns out that Office reformatted date to `yyyy/m/d` (based on your region). I'm developing a tool to process and import data to DB for my company, we did these work manually by copy and paste so no one noticed this issue. Thanks to [@Valdi_Bo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7388477/valdi-bo) for his investigate and patience.